# Trying to get property of non-object (the error notification said that the error is near at $data = ['name' => $validationData->name, ....] )

Tags: laravel

Is this correct? 
why am I getting this kind of error?
Trying to get property of non-object at MailController line 23 at data = 
[].
I've already checked to other solutions but there are no solutions that related to mine. 
Laravel Php Beginner here

here is my code

MainController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;<br>

use Illuminate\Http\Request;<br>
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;<br>
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;<br>
use App\Mail\ContactMessage;<br>

class MailController extends Controller
{
    public function post(Request $req) {

        $validationData = $this->validate($req, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'company' => 'required',
            'message' => 'required',
        ]);

        $data = [
            'name' => $validationData->name,
            'email' => $validationData->email,
            'phone' => $validationData->phone,
            'company' => $validationData->company,
            'message' => $validationData->message,
        ];

        Mail::to('avc@gmail.com')->send(new ContactMessage($data));

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

ContactMessage.php (Mailable)

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use App\User;

class ContactMessage extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        //
        $this->$data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('bca@gmail.com')
                    ->view('emails.contact');


    }
}
```

contact.blade.php (view)

```
<h3>You Got Mail!</h3>
<p>{{$data->message}}</p>
This is test number 1 of sending email
```

please help me thanks.

Comment: validate returns an array, not an object.  You're accessing validatedData as an object.

Comment: so what will I  do? I've somehow understood what you were saying ..

Comment: instead of 'name' => $validationData->name, i do it like this .. 'name' => $validationData['name'], .. is it correct? or wrong again?

Comment: Yes, that'd be the correct way to access an array.

Comment: There's actually no need to create the  $data array like this.  You're just creating an array with the same values.  Check the update/end of my answer.

Comment: I have another problem .. after I change all those stuff and when I tried to run it. it shows another error about "Array to string conversion" in ContactMessage.php

Comment: In your constructor, you have `$this->$data` instead of `$this->data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many similar duplicates but most seem to deal with arrays of objects.  This is a pretty simple issue, you're using the wrong access method for an array.

---

The validate method returns an array of validated inputs, not an object. You're accessing validatedData as an object (`->`) instead of an array.  Array keys are always accessed with brackets in PHP. (`$array['key']`)

I recommend using a debugger so you set a breakpoint and see the value of $validatedData.  You could also use `dd($validatedData)` to dump the value before hits the error line.

---

After reviewing your code further, there's no reason to have the redundant array created.  `$data` and `$validatedData` would be equivalent because validate already returns an array of those inputs.

```
   $data = $this->validate($req, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'company' => 'required',
        'message' => 'required',
   ]);

   Mail::to('avc@gmail.com')->send(new ContactMessage($data));
```

Comment: w8 .. there is just one last problem.. the sending of the mail is working but the problem is that I didn't show the data in the view that is sent from the mailable. in my code there in the view file.. is it correct? because i tried to access it by doing this "$data->message" and i've also tried this "$data['message']".. but still i didn't show the data or the result.

Comment: when i tried using this "$data->message" it shows an error about this again "Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\wamp64\www\activesystems-website\resources\views\emails\contact.blade.php)"

Comment: it should be `$data['message']`, it's good to hook up a debugger

Comment: Yes, that error is expected because you're still trying to access it as an object for some reason.

Comment: but why I'm still not able to see a result?

Comment: Not sure, that's why I recommended a debugger so you can trace the value of $data.  It should contain an array with message if your code looks like you've shown, you could always dump $data from the view to test.

Comment: can you recommend me a debugger if there is a tool or just a code?

Comment: Setting up xdebug with your IDE is definitely the best option.  Beyond that, you could use dd to dump and die like I suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `validate` function an error will be thrown early if it fails. So you don't need to worry about setting the values afterwards.

Take a look here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic.

I've made some changes below which should help.

```
public function post(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'company' => 'required',
        'message' => 'required',
    ]);

    $data = [
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'phone' => $request->phone,
        'company' => $request->company,
        'message' => $request->message,
    ];

    Mail::to('avc@gmail.com')->send(new ContactMessage($data));

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

You can also omit the $data array entirely if you wish by passing the response of `$request->validate()`.

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required',
    'phone' => 'required',
    'company' => 'required',
    'message' => 'required',
]);

Mail::to('avc@gmail.com')->send(new ContactMessage($validatedData));
```

Comment: There's really no need to create $data like this though, since validate would return an equivalent array.

Comment: @Devon Yes you are correct. My thinking when writing the answer was to keep it simple since they stated they were new to php / laravel.  I've updated the answer to also include this too.